# How to run a JavaScript .js file from an AJAX callback using native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to include and run the following from an AJAX callback (native JavaScript, no libraries):

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So the following works on all web browsers that I tested, except (of course) IE11:

```
var scrt = document.createElement("script");
scrt.setAttribute('async', '');
scrt.setAttribute('src', 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
scrt.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
document.body.appendChild(scrt);
```

IE shows no errors but the script from `widgets.js` is not executed.

So is there another way to do it that works with IE?

Comment: Can you try to do this:  twttr.widgets.load();   https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check if (when) twttr is available (loaded):

```
function checkTwitter() {
    if (!twttr.widgets) {
        setTimeout(checkTwitter.bind(this), 100);
    } else {
        // init:
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
}
setTimeout(checkTwitter.bind(this), 100);
```

See [twitter initialization](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization)

P.S.: I'm not sure if you have to write 'twttr.widgets' or 'window.twttr.widgets'

Comment: Thanks. If I do this in Chrome, `twttr.widgets.load()` executes just fine. But in IE11, right off the bat I get `'twttr' is undefined` and even if I add `if (!twttr || !twttr.widgets)` it just loops there forever. It seems like the script is not executed in IE after `document.body.appendChild(scrt);`. Is there any way to force it to parse it?